# Recursive backtracking - Maze generator

Tags: javascript, depth-first-search, maze

I'm trying to generate random maze using DFS algorithm, and I after watching several videos, I still can't get my head over it. I know how DFS algorithm works, but I have no idea, how to use this algorithm to actually create the maze.

There is the code that I'm using (Recursive Implementation):

```
const dirRow = [-1,+1,0,0];
const dirCol = [0,0,+1,-1];

// Given a current cell as a parameter
async function recursiveBacktracking(x,y){

    // While the current cell has any unvisited neighbour cells 
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        
        let newX = x + dirRow[i];
        let newY = y + dirCol[i];

        if (newX >= 20 || newX < 0) continue;
        if (newY >= 20 || newY < 0) continue;
        if (values[newY][newX].visited === true) continue;

        // Mark the current cell as visited
        values[newY][newX].visited = true;

        // Remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen cell
        if (values[newY][newX].neighbours[i] != null)
            values[newY][newX].neighbours[i].val = -1
        
        // Animation
        await renderPath(0,newX + newY*20);

        // Choose one of the unvisited neighbours
        await recursiveBacktracking(newX,newY);
    }   
}
```

I'm trying to follow the steps from the wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_backtracker),
and the part that I don't get, is that I have no idea which wall to remove on my 2d grid.

For the actual grid, I'm using 2d array with Node class on each X.

```
function Node(val, neighbours){
    this.val = val;
    this.neighbours = neighbours;
    this.visited = false;
}

function createNodeMap(w,h){
    let grid = []
    for (let y = 0; y < h; y++){
        grid.push([]);
        for (let x = 0; x < w; x++){
            grid[y].push(new Node(0, []));
        }
    }
    
    for (let y = 0; y < h; y++){
        for (let x = 0; x < w; x++){
            let neighbours= new Array(4).fill(null);
            if (x-1 >= 0) neighbours[0] = grid[y][x-1];
            if (x+1 < 20) neighbours[1] = grid[y][x+1];
            if (y+1 < 20) neighbours[2] = grid[y+1][x];
            if (y-1 >= 0) neighbours[3] = grid[y-1][x];
            grid[y][x].neighbours = neighbours;
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Grid that is created (Grey columns are the walls):[image]

**EDIT:**

Well the part where I'm marking the cell as part of the maze is wrong, because I'm not actually making any space for the walls to be in.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you are using for visualization/animation? I mean which library/package are you using? Also, can you please post a pic of your grid generated?

Comment: I'm just using custom function to color HTML elements based on index, and I've added the image of the grid to the original post.

Comment: Did you use the [DFS pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode) to make this? If so, I don't see the `while` in your code (which seems rather crucial to me).

Comment: I'm using the recursive method of DFS